# lightning:inputField disabled attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a custom lightning component to create Contact record.

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Contact">
    <lightning:messages />

    <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
    <lightning:inputField aura:id="account-field" 
                          fieldName="AccountId" 
                          value="{! v.accountId }" />

    <lightning:button type="submit" label="Create Contact" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

`AccountId` field is known upfront, how I can prevent users from editing it?

Answer (score 4):

Use  `ui:outputText` to show the account Id it cannot be edited.

```
<ui:outputText value="{!v.accountId}" />
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work. `<lightning:outputField fieldName="AccountId"  />` outputs only label "Account ID" in my form. `lightning:outputField` is intended to work with `lightning:recordFormView` only as I understand.

Comment: It displays Account Name if I specify contact id, but in my case I don't have contact id, since it is to create new record. I've removed recordId attribute from the `lightning:recordEditForm` tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: @edelrabe, my apologies oversight at my end. changed the answer to a simple output text. this should do for you

Answer (score 3):

just a little change from sunnyhell trick.
I just used it myselft with a minor change, I find it looks better with the following css:

```
.THIS .lookup-disabled, .THIS .lookup-disabled input {
    pointer-events: none;
    border: none;
}
.THIS .lookup-disabled button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is known issue about "disabled" attribute on lightning:inputField for lookups https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWo7QAG

This css trick works for me. 
Add css class to your lookup inputField, for example:

```
<lightning:inputField aura:id="account-field" 
                          fieldName="AccountId" 
                          value="{! v.accountId }"
                          class="lookup-disabled" />
```

And then in component bundle css add the following:

```
.THIS.lookup-disabled, .THIS.lookup-disabled input {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: rgb(236, 235, 234);
    border-color: rgb(201, 199, 197);
}
```